# How to treat 3rd party JSON which got syntax error?

Tags: jquery, json

I am obtaining JSON data form a 3rd party xsl file using the jQuery.getJSON. Sometimes this file has syntax error. This error is then silent, and I am unable to get data I look for.

The syntax error comes from lack of quotes around value:
`"title": -,`

I never really need the data from the object which holds the syntax error.
Is there a way to remove the whole object with syntax error? Or any other way to get around it so I can obtain data from lets say?

This is how the structure looks like:

```
{
    "stats": {
        "admin": "contact@email.com",
        "host": "address.com",
        "location": "Earth",
        "server_id": "Icecast 2.4.4",
        "server_start": "Sat, 18 Feb 2023 23:28:21 +0100",
        "server_start_iso8601": "2023-02-18T23:28:21+0100",
        "source": [{
            "authenticator": "url",
            "bitrate": 128,
            "genre": "Other",
            "listener_peak": 9,
            "listeners": 2,
            "listenurl": "http://address.com:8000/0001.ogg",
            "server_description": "Unspecified description",
            "server_name": "server name",
            "server_type": "audio/mpeg",
            "server_url": "http://www.example.com",
            "stream_start": "Sat, 18 Feb 2023 23:38:21 +0100",
            "stream_start_iso8601": "2023-02-18T23:38:21+0100",
            "title": "track title",
            "dummy": null
        }, {
            "audio_info": "ice-samplerate=44100;ice-bitrate=128;ice-channels=2",
            "authenticator": "url",
            "bitrate": 128,
            "genre": "various",
            "ice-bitrate": 128,
            "ice-channels": 2,
            "ice-samplerate": 44100,
            "listener_peak": 3,
            "listeners": 1,
            "listenurl": "http://address.com:8000/0006.ogg",
            "server_description": "Unspecified description",
            "server_name": "New Stream 1",
            "server_type": "audio/mpeg",
            "stream_start": "Sun, 19 Feb 2023 09:37:11 +0100",
            "stream_start_iso8601": "2023-02-19T09:37:11+0100",
            "title": -,
            "dummy": null
        }, {
            "authenticator": "url",
            "genre": "various",
            "listener_peak": 2,
            "listeners": 0,
            "listenurl": "http://address.com:8000/0099.ogg",
            "server_description": "desc",
            "server_name": "Live Air",
            "server_type": "audio/mpeg",
            "stream_start": "Sat, 18 Feb 2023 23:40:51 +0100",
            "stream_start_iso8601": "2023-02-18T23:40:51+0100",
            "dummy": null
        }]
    }
}
```

Edit. I need to retrieve data from other website (so cross-policy measures apply here), real-time and on interval. There is no JSON-P which I can use, so using the `jQuery.getJSON` was the only option I have found to make my use. And it works as long as there is no syntax error within the given JSON data. So if I was to "fix" the syntax myself to use it as JSON data, I would have to scrape it as raw text, treat it and then read as JSON. But the key is that getJSON function is the only one I found able to do what I want. Until it faces the silent error, when that function just quits without even warning.

Comment: Fix the problem at the source or request whoever maintains it to do so

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create json-paser to handle such cases. It may include, for instance, regex formatting like

```js
var wrong_json = // your json
var re = /"[\s]*:[\s]*-[\s]*/ ; // finds such minuses without quotes
var new_json = wrong_json.replace(re, '\" : \"-\"' );
```

Comment: I believe that will do, but how to get the content of the online file into the wrong_json variable? I used `jQuery.getJSON(https://address.com/jsonstats.xsl, function(jsondata){}` to obtain the data, but it fails as a whole whenever the file itself contain syntax error.